# Error at /myservice1-cicd-stack The filter 'null' is invalid

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I am trying to follow along the the tutorial for setting up CICD pipeline using [AWS CDK.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/prescriptive-guidance/latest/patterns/automatically-build-ci-cd-pipelines-and-amazon-ecs-clusters-for-microservices-using-aws-cdk.html)
Under the section Create a CI/CD pipeline for a microservice - Create the infrastructure for the microservice it instructs to rename the service name. I am not sure where exactly to change this service name. I keep getting the above error and cannot figure out what it means.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from aws_cdk import core

from cdkpipeline.cdkpipeline_stack import CdkpipelineStack

app = core.App()

aws_account = app.node.try_get_context("aws_account")
aws_region = app.node.try_get_context("aws_region")
microservice_name = app.node.try_get_context("microservice_name")

env = core.Environment(account=aws_account, region=aws_region)

app_stack_name = "myservice1" + "-cicd-stack"
CdkpipelineStack(app, app_stack_name , env=env)
app.synth()
```

Answer (score 0):

I once got this error because of an environment was null because of that the filter values was null. So check these `aws_account` and `aws_account` values are correctly passed to the CDK script through the context.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when one of the context variables value is not passed in the synth or deploy command. Always check what are you expecting in code and pass those values in context.